# Visual Studio Code's problem tab text is garbled

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code, junit5, junit-jupiter

I created a Java application project using `gradle init` (with [JUnit Jupiter](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/)).

When I opened the project in Visual Studio Code, the *Problem* tab text was garbled like the below screen capture.

[Visual Studio Code screen capture with garbled problem tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfGNV.png)

Messages in the tab are like this: `�p�b�P�[�Worg.junit.jupiter.api�͑��݂��܂���`.

Is there a solution?

### Version Information

#### Visual Studio Code

```
Version: 1.52.0 (user setup)
Commit: 940b5f4bb5fa47866a54529ed759d95d09ee80be
Date: 2020-12-10T22:45:11.850Z
Electron: 9.3.5
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041
```

#### Java

```sh
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

#### Gradle Version

```sh
gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------       
Gradle 6.7.1
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Looks like it could be an issue with the terminal that's being emulated in the Visual Studio code browser sending control characters (say, changing colour) but your terminal that's being emulated isn't recognising the control characters.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I don't know the causal relationship, 
but when I turn on the setting: User - Files - Auto Guess Encoding,
the problem tab display has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the setting: menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* → *User* → *Text Editor* → *Files* → *Auto Guess Encoding*